# PHP cyrillic is encoded when echoing in db query

Tags: php

I've got php function like that:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo '<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Альбом: ' .$row['album'].'<br /></span>';
  echo '<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Рік: ' .$row['release_year'].'<br /></span>';
  echo '<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Країна: ' .$row['country'].'<br /></span>';
  echo '<span style="font-size: 10pt;">Жанр: ' .$row['genre'].'<br /></span>';
}
```

output:

```
РђР»СЊР±РѕРј: Away From the Sun
Р С–Рє: 2001
РљСЂР°С—РЅР°: Germany
Р–Р°РЅСЂ: Rock
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Document's header has charset to utf8?

Comment: @user3783243 yep. As you can see - problem's with HTML text as `Альбом`

Comment: data from DB is echoing normally

Comment: Yes, noticed it wasnt db/mysql related after first comment so removed it. Can you show how HTML headers are being sent and which they are? Proper MVCE would have been `echo 'Альбом';` gives `РђР»СЊР±РѕРј`. The other content and tags cluttered the issue.

Comment: @user3783243 sorry I misunderstood you. I thought that you meant that sql query should be set with utf-8

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">` helped!